# Table with vertical header (sortable)

Tags: css, sorting, css-tables

I am working on vertical table with header as sortable using following code. Column are vertical but how can they be sorted by clicking header.

**CSS Code:**

```
 <style>
#tabs{

}
```

[image]

```
#vartabs .ui-widget-header {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
}

#vartabs .ui-widget-content {
  background-color: white;
  background-image: none;

}

#vartabs .ui-corner-top,#tabs .ui-corner-bottom,#tabs .ui-corner-all{
  border-top-left-radius: 0px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}



#vartabs .ui-state-default,
#vartabs .ui-state-default a {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#vartabs .ui-state-default a {
  width: herepx;
}


#vartabs .ui-tabs-active,
#vartabs .ui-tabs-active a {
  background-color: darkgray;
  text-align: center;

}

 </style>


 <style>
     th.rotate {
  /* Something you can count on */
  height: 140px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

th.rotate > div {
  transform: 
    /* Magic Numbers */
    translate(0px, 51px)
    /* 45 is really 360 - 45 */
    rotate(270deg);
    width: 8px;
}
th.rotate > div > span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}


table tbody 
{
   overflow: auto;
   height: 10px;
}



.scroll {
    max-height: 700px;
    overflow: auto;
}
th
{
    width: 72px;
}


 </style>
```

I found another code on net for sorting table but it is bit difficult to merge to codes as their logic is bit different.

Comment: It looks like you're just starting up? It might be better to use something off the shelf, like this jQuery plugin? http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: But these are not vertical columns.

Comment: Not clear on what you mean, the plugin I linked to has vertical columns. Perhaps edit and add screenshot of your table to the post?

Comment: I just posted screen shots.

Comment: I mean vertical header.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sort tables just with HTML and CSS. You'll either need to do it on the client via JavaScript, or server-side via whatever programming language you're using to generate the page.

Comment: i know but any working example will surely help me a lot.